# Compiling with FreeGLUT in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opengl, freeglut

I'm trying to compile some examples from NVIDIA. I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. I figured out most of the issues, but I can't get the last one right:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in
>   function _glutSwapBuffers in
>   ...Samples\NvDecodeGL\freeglut_staticd.lib(fg_display.obj)

I already added **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** to my linker inputs.
What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Is your freeglut library compiled for visual studio 2017? [Read this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1144980/error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-iob-func)

Comment: I'm not sure. It is the latest version I could find. But since when do libraries need to be compiled for a specific IDE? That's just madness ;-)

Comment: Libraries always need to be compiled for a specific compiler. Did you read the article linked?

Comment: @ BDL, this link has been retired. Regards.